# Some podcasts missing from Smart Playlist

Tags: podcasts, playlist, smart-playlist

Using the latest iTunes under Windows 10, I have created a Smart Playlist as follows, requiring that ALL conditions be met:

```
1. Media Kind is Podcast
2. Play Count = 0
3. Location is "this computer"
4. Rating is not equal to one star
```

I have selected only the "Live Updating" check-box.

The resulting playlist includes some/most of the podcasts I expect, but not all of them.

I checked the details of some of the missing podcasts, but could not determine why they are not included -- they match all of the conditions of the playlist. Why are they not included?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in iTunes 12.3.1.23.

I created a similar playlist to the one in my question, but I replaced the "Rating" condition with "is equal to one star".

This new playlist contained all the "missing" podcasts. However, the "Get Info" for many of these podcasts indicated that the rating was NOT one star. These podcasts showed in the playlist with a grey star. Podcasts, which were actually rated with one star, showed in the playlist with a black star.

Comment: Further to this: Any podcast in the playlist for which I selected "Get Info" subsequently appeared in a second entry in the main podcasts list in iTunes.

Comment: Changing all the one star rating to five stars and then changing the queries in the playlists accordingly seems to have solved this.